self-written BMP files with RLE8 compression not recognized by readers like Preview
I am trying to write BMP image files using RLE8 compression. Most files I read/write are recognized by standard readers, but some fail. Images with large blank areas are not recognized unless they are quite small (<512x512). However, images with complex color patterns are recognized, even when very large.
This is problematic because RLE compression works best with simple images, and my images of interest are mainly simple line drawings—exactly the kind that fails. BMP files with RLE8 compression, generated by others, have headers, color tables, and RLE code strings identical in format to mine, as far as I can tell. The success or failure seems to depend on the pattern of colors in the image: simple blank images fail, while complex images work.
Is there some sort of checksum or other validation that these files must pass? I see no systematic difference between my images and those generated by others that are recognized.
I’ve tested images of many sizes and aspect ratios. Blank images beyond a small size are not recognized by standard readers. The same code works well for both self-generated images and many standard test images, as long as they aren't too simple. I’ve compared RLE codes for images generated by others, and they seem identical (mutatis mutandis) to my own.
Additional Info: Microsoft apps like Paint display all my images without any issues. So, the problem seems to lie in Apple reader apps. Does anyone know if this is a known issue, and if so, how to work around it?
I haven't found an Apple app that can display the "invalid" images. I've tried Preview, FreeForm, ColorSync Utility, and the image import function in Word. All of these work with the smaller images but fail to recognize larger ones as a valid graphic format.
Example:
Here are two RLE8 image files:
The first one is flagged as invalid by readers.
The second one is almost identical, but it is read and displayed correctly.
Both files use the same RLE codes, but the first file is for a 1024x64 image (64 lines), and the second is for a 1024x32 image (32 lines). Aside from the number of lines and corresponding differences in the headers, the files are the same.


BM                     BM
file_size              1846
reserved1              0
reserved2              0
offset_to_pixels       1078
info_header_size       40
xpix                   1024
ypix                   64
planes                 1
bits_per_pixel         8
compression            1
bytes_in_pixel_block   768
xpixelspermeter        0
ypixelspermeter        0
colors_used            256
colors_important       256



RLE Code Block (Flagged as invalid):


Line  0: 255,111 255,111 255,111 255,111 4,111 0, 0
Line  1: 255,111 255,111 255,111 255,111 4,111 0, 0
...
Line 63: 255,111 255,111 255,111 255,111 4,111 0, 1



Valid File


BM                     BM
file_size              1462
reserved1              0
reserved2              0
offset_to_pixels       1078
info_header_size       40
xpix                   1024
ypix                   32
planes                 1
bits_per_pixel         8
compression            1
bytes_in_pixel_block   384
xpixelspermeter        0
ypixelspermeter        0
colors_used            256
colors_important       256



RLE Code Block (Valid):


Line  0: 255,111 255,111 255,111 255,111 4,111 0, 0
Line  1: 255,111 255,111 255,111 255,111 4,111 0, 0
...
Line 31: 255,111 255,111 255,111 255,111 4,111 0, 1



Summary:
The RLE lines are the same for both files, except the first has 64 lines, while the second has 32. However, the first one is flagged as invalid. Could it be related to some limit in the Apple reader or something else I’m overlooking?

You haven't shared the code used to create the images, or the images (use Google Drive or Dropbox). As such this is not a [mcve].

Random guess: I wonder if this is some kind of defense against zip bombs? You have a very small file decompressing to a substantial amount of pixel data. FWIW, I can’t see anything that is significantly different between these two files; although I haven’t downloaded them, the files seem like they adhere to Microsoft’s spec.

It might be worth trying to figure out how big the image has to be before it breaks. Maybe 65536 pixels or 32768 pixels is the magic threshold. What happens if you replace “255,111” with e.g. “128,111 127,111”? Have you tried this with any open source software, where we might be able to check the source code of the BMP decoder?

Here are links to the two images on Google drive:                                           Image that is accepted   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cpLg_bMj0-3J8t6o3Pju2-5wz2h1cuwP/view?usp=share_link                                              Image that is considered invalid    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x3jRustFvXIq7D4d7E-aV9wGouN2dRud/view?usp=share_link

How big the image has to be before it breaks: it depends on aspect ratio (and also on color patterns in the image (which affect the RLE codes of course), so there is no simple answer. For images with only single-color lines 1024x62 works, 1024x63 does not. But images with diagonal lines from corner to corner, so no blank lines, still break, if they are big enough.

Here is a link to an image with a criss-cross, 1024x418, that works: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sfhXfUKThwPXdaSSTssH_rb0gVbjw_ae/view?usp=share_link     Here is the same image but 1024x419 that breaks: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OQFuEhEO-MD0TWDbpBrx5EYhWFktCuYN/view?usp=share_link

Here is an image that breaks, 1536x512, but only grayscale: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YLWH-xiZmK9Qt7-OWu_BgQSVJLYYlviF/view?usp=share_link       Here is the same image, same size, but with various colors for the lines. This one works: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19D7Xtjj6nmqpJeiI3T9NZwII2qqxJcD_/view?usp=share_link


The Google drive display, and also Windows reader/display programs, work with all of these images, so the problem is with the Apple apps, not the images per se. 2) I have tried many variants but there is no simple pattern. The Apple apps (mainly Preview) are doing something strange. I'm hoping someone knows the specifics of how, say, Preview tests images for validity, so some sort of work-around can be found.


FWIW, iPad Photos app also fails or succeeds in the same way as Preview and other apps on Mac. So it seems to be a general Apple issue. Windows apps always work (so far as I've tested), and whatever Google is using for image display also works.

Your photos on Google Drive are not accessible.

This app  https://www.xnview.com/en/  correctly displays all images, and gives correct header info and compression type, etc, for all images, on Mac. So again, the issue is the Apple apps (for both Mac OS types and iOS types, apparently) not the files themselves.

Your images are still not publicly accessible.

Is there some setting or permission I need to give in Google drive, beyond the links themselves in the earlier comments? I've never used a general public link before. I don't see an obvious option necessary to make them accessible to everyone. I thought they would be accessible already.

They are currently inaccessible. You should have received Emails requesting access for at least 3 of them.

Emails went to spam. You should have access now

To answer my own question, as far as I can at the moment: all the Apple image display programs fail to recognize BMP images with RLE8 compression, for simple line images with mostly one-color background, above a certain size. In folder windows they don't show a thumbnail. When clicked they give an error message. But these same files open without issue in Windows apps on Windows machines, and display correctly in Google drive. Also at least some non-Apple apps that run on Macs read and display the images correctly in all particulars. It's clear that the Apple image readers/display apps apply some non-obvious validity test that some valid BMP images do not pass. I have not been able to figure out what the test is, despite running many cases.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254222151?=undefined&previousThread=254193524021&sortBy=rank
